# The method method(com.here.A) in the type Some is not applicable for the arguments (com.somewhereelse.A)

Tags: java

I have class A.class in package `com.here`:

```
public class A {
String a;
}
```

And I have class A in different library in package `com.somwehereelse`:

```
public class A {
String a;
}
```

And I have Some.class and I call method

```
public class Some{
public someMethod(A a){
method(a);
}
}
```

Class A and B differs package. But I am able to only use A.class from `com.here` package, when I try to use A.class from `com.somewhereelse.A` I obtain error:

> The method method(com.somewhereelse.A) in the type Some is not applicable for
>   the arguments (com.here.A).

How to pass as argument A.class from library of `com.somewhereelse` package? If I can't change packages.

Comment: You can’t.  They are two totally different classes with no relationship between them, so I’m not sure what you think you would achieve.  If there is some common functionality between them, you could create an interface that you have them both implement, and change your method to expect that interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, they are fundamentally different types (even if they look the same, minus package).

You *could* generify your `someMethod` method to accept either though.

```
public <T> void someMethod(final T instance, final Function<T, String> stringGetter) {
    final String value = stringGetter.apply(instance);

    // Do whatever you want with the String
}
```

Where you can call this with something like:

```
someMethod(new A(), A::getA);
```

---

There are other approaches (common interfaces, reflection, proxies, duck-typing).  But this is probably the least work, and doesn't require modifying either of the `A` classes (which I assume if you *could* do, you wouldn't be having this issue...).

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change the implementation of `A` in either package to e.g. have a common interface (polymorphism is probably the smartest solution), you could also use proxies and reflection as BeUndead suggested in his absolutely correct answer.

And here is an example how (renamed `com.somwehereelse.A` to `B` and added setter/getter), using CGLib:

```
public class TypingTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <FROM, TO> TO duckTypedProxy(final FROM delegate, final Class<TO> toClass) {
        TO duckTypedProxy;

        final Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(toClass);
        enhancer.setInterfaces(toClass.getInterfaces());
        enhancer.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args, proxy) -> {
            final Method delegateMethod = delegate.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            return delegateMethod.invoke(delegate, args);
        });

        duckTypedProxy = (TO) enhancer.create();

        return duckTypedProxy;
    }

    @Test
    public void testTyping() {
        final A real = new A();
        real.setA("a");

        final B other = new B();
        other.setA("b");

        final A fake = duckTypedProxy(other, A.class);

        acceptA(real);
        acceptA(fake);
    }

    private void acceptA(final A a) {
        System.out.println(a.getA());
    }
}
```

Comment: Bless you for giving an example.  I didn't have time to do this, otherwise I'd've included something similar in my answer :).  (Note: I haven't checked this works, but it looks about right.)